# Cognito Post confirmation being triggered multiple times

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

Saw this question on reddit and believe it should be brought over to stack overflow after having the same issue (https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/bzvhu3/cognito_post_confirmation_being_triggered/)

For some reason, even though `"triggerSource"` is `"PostConfirmation_ConfirmSignUp"` both times for my cognito user pool sign up, it's getting run twice as seen in `CloudWatch` logs. The second time fails because the user has already been in the database, what is the issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Amazon Cognito invokes Lambda functions synchronously. When called, your Lambda function must respond within 5 seconds. If it does not, Amazon Cognito retries the call. After 3 unsuccessful attempts, the function times out. This 5-second timeout value cannot be changed"

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-triggers.html#important-lambda-considerations

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I was using Zappa for cognito lambda event handler, to send multiple teams webhook. But due to this "5 second timeout" the notifications were sent out multiple times. Moved the webhook sending logic to a zappa async task and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 7):

The issue is that your timeout setting is over 5 seconds, if it waits for 6 seconds, by the 5 second mark it will trigger again as if it fails.

**Interesting Note**: I had to bump my timeout to 10s because my stripe api was taking a while for some reason when I had 4s as the timeout it would often fail. After bumping to 10s timeout it no longer fails.... but it still averages a 2s execution time so it never runs twice. Not sure why this is, but it's good to be aware of.

**Second note**: I was unable to find documentation about this 5 second timeout retry, I did note it to be true though. If anyone has the location of this documentation please add it.

Comment: where do you update the timeout?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-triggers.html

Comment: Based on your given document that mentioned the default timeout is 5s and it will retry 3 times. And these values are not changeable. How could you update the timeout? Or you mentioned the timeout configuration inside the lambda function

Comment: this was from a while ago, but I do believe at the time there was some option for timeout that I changed